# PHP, Google TimeZone API and JSON issue

Tags: php, json, google-api

I'm having an issue with the JSON response from the Google Timezone API.

```
$epochTimestamp = time();

$urlTZ = ' https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?' . http_build_query(
[
    'location' =>  $location,
    'timestamp' => $epochTimestamp,
    'key' => $GOOGLE_MAP_API
]
);

$urlTZ = htmlspecialchars($urlTZ, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$chTZ = curl_init($urlTZ);
curl_setopt($chTZ, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseTZ = curl_exec($chTZ);

print("<br/>" . $urlTZ . "<br/>");
print("<br/>Response:");
var_dump($responseTZ);

$jsonTZ = json_decode($responseTZ, true);
print("<br/>JSON:");
var_dump($jsonTZ);
```

The result is:

```
Response:bool(false) 
JSON:NULL
```

Which seems to point to an error with my call. But, if I take the generated URL and paste it on my web browser, I do get a JSON response:

```
{
"dstOffset" : 0,
"rawOffset" : -28800,
"status" : "OK",
"timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
"timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

I've tried get_contents instead of curl, same result.

Note: I have a similar code to get geolocation information from Google API, and it works fine ...

Any idea what's happening here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$epochTimestamp = time();

$urlTZ = ' https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?' . http_build_query(
[
'location' =>  $location,
'timestamp' => $epochTimestamp,
'key' => $GOOGLE_MAP_API
]
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlTZ);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$responseTZ = curl_exec($ch);


print("<br/>" . $urlTZ . "<br/>");
print("<br/>Response:");
var_dump($responseTZ);

$jsonTZ = json_decode($responseTZ, true);
print("<br/>JSON:");
var_dump($jsonTZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. `$urlTZ = ' https` remove space before https so it would be `$urlTZ = 'https`
2. remove this line `$urlTZ = htmlspecialchars($urlTZ, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` because it replace & and thus build invalid url

Comment: Thank you Muhammed. The problem with removing the htmlspecialchars function is that &timestamp would be changed to xstamp and the URL won't be correct ...

Comment: @OlivierS sorry for late reply. Hope you fixed it already. Btw, what did you mean &timestamp will change to xstamp?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location='.$lat.','.$lng.'&timestamp='.time().'&key='.$GOOGLE_MAP_API;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```